# How to do something with every second object in a NSArray? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, object, loops, for-loop, nsarray

I have a NSArray with many NSDictionaries. I'm using `for` to loop through it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {

 }
```

Now I want to do something with every second object of the array. Let's say the array has an ***count*** of 5. Than it will do something with the 2nd, 4th and 5th object.

How can I do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
           if //check if it is the second object 
     }
```

EDIT: Every second object and the last object if one will remain..

Comment: Do you mean to say every second *and* the last? Because "every second" doesn't include the fifth, by definition.

Comment: @yan Yes every second and if one object remains that too,

Answer (score 7):

You can either increment by two during your loop increment or multiply by two when accessing.

i.e.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i += 2) {
  doStuff([myArray objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]/2; i++) {
   doStuff([myArray objectAtIndex:i*2]);
}
```

Comment: but in the first method: Wouldn't it crash because of a "index out of bounds"?

Comment: No because the test portion of the for loop still needs to be true for the loop to execute. The way the loop is set up is such that `i < [myArray count]` will always be true if the body is being executed. That is to say, the test happens before the loop executes, and the increment happens after.

Answer (score 4):

It might be better to use [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) if you don't need the index:

```
BOOL odd = YES; 
for (id obj in ary) {
    odd = !odd;
    if (odd) continue;
    // do stuff
}
```

When `odd` is initialized, before the loop, consider the implicit index (`i` in a traditional for loop) to be -1. (Which is an odd number.) On the first iteration of the loop, the index is incremented to 0, and the `odd` flag is flipped to even (`NO`). The flag is not odd, so we run this iteration (index 0, 1st element). The next iteration increments the index to 1 (2nd element), and the flag is inverted to odd. Since the flag is odd, we skip this iteration. Execution continues like this until the end of the array.

Edit: The traditional for loop with an index is cleaner if you always want to operate on the last element. To do that here, you would need to track the index manually or repeat the loop contents after the loop.

Comment: could you explain this? I don't really understand what you're doing.

Comment: @cocos2dbeginner I added some explanation to my question. For something trivial like this though, it doesn't really matter which method is used. Use whichever is clearest to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator:

```
if (i % 2 || (i == [myArray count] - 1)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The modulo returns the remainder of the division i/2.
So if i is 0 (**first item**), it is 0 (==**false**).
If i is 1 (**second item**), it is 1 (==**true**).

To get your last element I added the `(i == [myArray count] - 1)` condition.

Comment: what does this do? Could you explain it a little bit?